# How do I populate getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, clockkit

so this tutorial here is excellent

http://www.sneakycrab.com/blog/2015/6/10/writing-your-own-watchkit-complications

and this tells me that I need to set the fillFraction, ringStyle and textProvider, but its not jumping out to me from the docs what I need to do in objective c, and I've tried many combinations I can think of.
can anyone assist in my understanding of completing the boiler plate code in the new watchOS complication template?

```
- (void)getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(__nullable CLKComplicationTemplate *complicationTemplate))handler {
    /

    switch (complication.family) {
        case CLKComplicationFamilyCircularSmall:

            // WHAT DO I PUT HERE? confused.com

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

i'm wanting to test out a small circular complication with updates from my ios app.

anyone aid my understanding before I go all in on swift?

many thanks
Nik

update after a brief chat with @mipadi :-) and a minor tweak.

```
- (void)getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(__nullable CLKComplicationTemplate *complicationTemplate))handler {
    switch (complication.family) {
        case CLKComplicationFamilyCircularSmall:
        {
            CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingText *myComplicationTemplate; // Create template object
            myComplicationTemplate.fillFraction = 0.7;
            myComplicationTemplate.ringStyle = CLKComplicationRingStyleOpen;
            handler(myComplicationTemplate);
        }
        default:
            break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this crash? I think you need to put something like `CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingText *myComplicationTemplate = [[CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingText alloc] init];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create an instance of a `CLKComplicationTemplate` and pass it to the handler:

```
- (void)getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(__nullable CLKComplicationTemplate *complicationTemplate))handler {
    switch (complication.family) {
    case CLKComplicationFamilyCircularSmall: {
        CLKComplicationTemplate *myComplicationTemplate = [CLKComplicationTemplate new]; 
        // Create your template object
        handler(myComplicationTemplate);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks. For CLKComplication *myComp; I get the error 'Expected expression'. and for handler(myComp) 'User of undeclared identifier myComp'. any ideas?

Comment: its exactly as yours above :-)

Comment: @NikBurns: I don't see `CLKComplication *myComp;` at all in that code, so I don't know where that error would be coming from.

Comment: saving space, myComp = myComplicationTemplate

Comment: @NikBurns: Need braces around the code in the first `case` statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80815/discussion-between-nik-burns-and-mipadi).